# Flutter Keyboard opening with resizeToAvoidBottomInset has a weird gap

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `SingleChildScrollView` containing some `TextFormFields`. In order for the keyboard to push the scroll view up, I set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` in my scaffold.

I notice there is blank/gap when the keyboard pops, as the scroll view seems to be pushed faster than the keyboard appears.

On a native app, this behavior does not exist.

[image]

Here is a simple example:

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  TestWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  Widget _getInput() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      height: 75.0,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.cyan,
      child: TextFormField(
        initialValue: 'Some Random Input',
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flutter draws the screen 120 times per second.
So that's what happens on smartphones with low performance.
The method is that if you select the Scaffold Backgournd color as the same color, this phenomenon does not appear much.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
                _getInput(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.cyan, // background color setting
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's odd. It does it on my physical iPhone Xs